# JPA OUTER JOIN without relation

Tags: jpa, outer-join

I need make `OUTER JOIN` of two entities in JPA (saying master, detail), but the problem that at the entity level there are no relations (and I don't want add it).

```java
@Entity
class Master
{
    @Column(name="altKey")
    Integer altKey;
}

@Entity
class Detail
{
    @Column(name="altKeyRef")
    @Basic (optional = true)
    Integer altKeyRef;
}
```

```sql
SELECT m, d FROM Master m OUTER JOIN ????? d.altKeyRef = m.altKey
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of the spec (see 4.14 BNF) is that a `[ LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN` mush be done along a path expression (either a single valued association field or a collection valued association field).

Comment: in other word you talking about impossibility to accomplish this without relation?